# Я хочу написать класс кнопки, как эффективнее распорядится памятью и какие типы данных использовать?

Tags: c++, классы, память, switch

Итак, у меня есть класс

```
class Screep
{
public:
    char GetButton()
    {
        return this->Button;
    }
    void SetButton(char* NameButton)
    {
        if (NameButton == "PIPA")
        {
            this->Button = *NameButton;
        }
    }     
private:
    char Button;
```

По моей изначальной задумке Button это название кнопки, например "EXIT".
Уже в процессе написания функции я понял, что switch не работает для char и вообще char это только одна буква в данном случае(Так ведь? Просто 8 бит?)
Я попробовал по другому определить переменную Button

```
private: 
char* Button[4];
```

Я думал, что так получится сделать каждую кнопку из четырёх букв, но ничего не вышло(я не знаю как разобраться со строкой this->Button если это массив, например я пробовал

```
this->Button[0]=*NameButton
```

Но это к сожалению не сработало. 
Ещё я смог всё это сделать через string и это работало, но моя программа вместо 30 мбайт памяти стала жрать 270 и я решил отказаться от этого варианта. 
Теперь остался вариант вместо имени использовать просто число int может быть наверху для удобства определить что-то типа #define PIPA 1;

Вопрос - какой из вариантов используется в реальных программах и какой наименьший тип int мне использовать? У меня будут числа меньше 200 скорее всего, так что какой int самый короткий?

Comment: `std::string` - самое лучше решение, имхо. *"через string и это работало, но моя программа вместо 30 мбайт памяти стала жрать 270"* Именно мегабайт, это не опечатка? Сколько кнопок вы храните одновременно? Если немного, то дело не в `std::string`, а в программе...

Comment: я храню массив Screep(это мой класс), он описывает весь экран, а в нём каждый пиксель и какой кнопке он принадлежит, то есть много... Я сейчас подумал, что можно было хранить только "отрезки" границ кнопок и через if определять нажал ли я на кнопку, но по-моему такое решение какое-то ограниченное и не получится нормально сделать не прямоугольные кнопки

Comment: О я понял, можно сделать много bool переменных и проверять какой из кнопок принадлежит пиксель, но конечно это тоже странное решение

Comment: Один экземпляр на каждый пиксель?! Лучше храните просто список кнопок, и для каждой - координаты и размер. Когда пользователь кликает на пиксель - проходите по всем списку и выбирайте подходящую. Если нужны кнопки произвольной формы - в дополнение к размерам храните для каждой кнопки функцию, которая проверяет, принадлежит ли отдельный пиксель в прямоугольнике этой кнопки самой кнопке. А если у вас неприлично много кнопок и простой список не подходит, можно попробовать что-то в духе [BVH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy).

Comment: ну тут проблема 1. список всё же не бесконечный, его конечно можно сделать длинным, но всё равно ограничения. и 2. у меня могут быть кнопки внутри кнопки, а это необоснованно усложняет процесс

Comment: *"список всё же не бесконечный"* Насколько много кнопок вам нужно? *"могут быть кнопки внутри кнопки, а это необоснованно усложняет процесс"* Тогда можно хранить кнопки в дереве. Мне кажется, это совршенно обычное дело.

Comment: "Тогда можно хранить кнопки в дереве.Мне кажется, это совершенно обычное дело". Ну для меня не такое обычное, это мой первый вообще проект хоть сколько нибудь серьёзный